# How to release a UDP socket that was not closed

Tags: python, udp

I failed to close my socket in the following test:

```
UDP_IP = "my.ip"
UDP_PORT = 5005


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        my_socket.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
        #(snip)
```

So, the next time I'm running this thing, I'm getting the following error:

```
my_socket.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Of course, I can always use another port. However, I'm wondering if I can release the port which I failed to close properly?

Comment: I think it's done by the OS.

Comment: You will have to kill the process and there might also be some waiting time from the OS.

Comment: Did you try restarting? I think that **you** can do anything, but maybe the OS can

Comment: @KlausD. Yes I've stopped the process, and eventually the port was released, but not right now.

Comment: @Neo I'm restarting the box would help, but I wanted something more lightweight.

Comment: You could use a docker container. Every container has an isolated network stack.